# My iPad is over taken by someone, windows open by themselves, items get selected by themselves, I have no control of my iPad

Tags: ipad

My iPad is over taken by someone.  I have windows open by themselves, items get selected by themselves, I have no control of my iPad most of the time I try to use it.  When I talk to it, telling it to stop or ask silly questions, words will highlight on the screen as if whomever is answering me.  I cannot delete apps because someone has remotely changed my "Restrictions Password" & I can't download any apps from iTunes to check for Spyware.  How can I find the app or other bug that is allowing someone to spy on me remotely?

Comment: I don't even think that's possible in iOS.  What version of iOS are you using?  Is this a jailbroken device?  It sounds like you have one of the Accessibility features turned on.

Comment: If your restriction password is set to an unknown value you may need to reset/reinstall your iPad.

Comment: Does your iPad display this behaviour if you're not trying to do anything? That is, if your iPad is on and you're not touching the screen at all and not speaking to it at all, is it glitching, opening windows, etc? Or does it just sit there with the screen on?

Comment: who beside you had physical access to the phone?

Comment: @fsb - iOS version 9.3.5 - it's over taken by someone or something. For example:  I had made a "note" using IPad Notes App, labeled "Your Ignorant". I was trying to make a 'new' note for something else, the app stalled. When I'm not even touching the screen, the tab "Your Ignorant" began flipping back-n-forth. I said "I know I'm Ignorant" & the tab stopped moving, as if someone was listening.  I've had info put into my Google search window that I've never searched for.

Comment: When I am trying to search for something, cursor in the 'search box', multiple tabs open by themselves before I can finish typing. If my iPad is JailBroken, I don't know.  No one has ANY physical contact with my iPad, a passcode is needed to unlock my iPad. I've told no one what my passcode is & change it often.

Comment: I can't even remove apps because the 'X' doesn't appear when it wiggles.